# Swift inflated [UInt8] fails to deflate with miniz lib

Tags: ios, swift, zlib, deflate, miniz

I have an iOS app where I use [DeflateSwift](https://github.com/tidwall/DeflateSwift) to deflate a byte array (`[UInt8]`). When I try to inflate this data using the [miniz](https://code.google.com/p/miniz/) library it is not working. This is executed in another platform. The [DeflateSwift](https://github.com/tidwall/DeflateSwift) is a very simple wrapper around the zlib library which have been around for ages.

I have tried to set different value on `windowsBits` as well as `compressionLevel` when doing the inflate in the app. This has not solved the problem. The [miniz](https://code.google.com/p/miniz/) use `windowsBits = 15` by default which is the default setting for [DeflateSwift](https://github.com/tidwall/DeflateSwift) as well.

According to the documentation [miniz](https://code.google.com/p/miniz/) should be 100% compatible with zlib, which does not seems to be the case.

Has anybody else encountered similar problems? Are there any more settings than `windowsBits` & `compressionLevel` that I could fiddle with?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out I did not get the DeflateSwift classes to work with the miniz library. However the `NSData+Compression` found in [CocoaGit](https://github.com/schacon/igithub/tree/master/CocoaGit) works for this.